# uigetfile not pulling entire file name

Tags: matlab

I'm using uigetfile to upload my data. I've time stamped my data with a date.  So a file I want to upload looks like Data-Dec01_11/45/35.txt  The problem is uigetfile reads till the first "/" and then assumes that that is the end of the file name. Thus it pulls the file name `Data-Dec01_11`. But of course when I load that file it doesn't exist. How do I force uigetfile to pull the entire file name?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use slashes or backslashes in your file names, as they can be mistaken with the file separator, as in your case.

You can use ´regexpr´ to rename your files so they do not contain illegal characters, as explained [in this trhead](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/149298).

I copy here the code they suggest for your convenience (I've just added a slash and a backslash to the example string so you can see the results):

```
% these characters are allowed
  legalchars = 'a-zA-Z0-9\-\ \_\.' ;
% illegal filename
  A = 'Some@charac\ters$are(not&allowed/.txt'
% replace every other character with an underscore
  B = regexprep(A,['[^' legalchars ']'],'_')
```